# Laravel: How do I pass a model to every view if a Session variable is present?

Tags: laravel

In laravel, my session has a user_id in it.  I'd like to fetch the row from the User's table with that id and pass it as a variable to every view.

I tried creating a service provider but the session was empty (I put it as the last service).

Any tips appreciated.

I'm not using the built in Auth module

Comment: Why not just use `auth()->user()` to access the logged-in user?

Comment: I'm not using the inbuilt user module.

Comment: you can only used `auth()->user()` if @user3780104 uses `Auth::attempt()` to login

Comment: First: You should update your question to make clear that u are not using the built in auth module. Second: have a look at the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want you can create a helper function that can do this for you

on your composer json file

```
"autoload-dev" : {
    "files" : [
         'path/to/helper.php'
     ]
}
```

then on your helper.php

```
function getActiveUser() {
   return App\User::find(session('userId'));
}
```

there are numerous ways you can do this. this one is one of them. . but i prefer to use the built-in auth module to handle it

Comment: this is now a global function. . means you can call it in your view or anywhere in your app. .

Comment: yeah that's true. But you have to call that global function in every view. There is no $data passed to that views. The OP's question states that he wanted to pass some data directly to the views without calling global functions at all. Your solution is an alternative ( + 1 for that ) but does not address the concrete  needs of the OP

Comment: @shock_gone_wild If you call the helper function `user()`, it seems to me like `{{ user() }}` is just as easy as `{{ $user }}` in the views. It answers the question even if it's not the exact narrow solution the OP was looking into.

Comment: thank you the alternative is potentially going to be useful to me elsewhere!  Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @ceejayoz you are right. that's why i have upvoted that answer ;) It is right in general and as I said it's an alternative to original needs

Answer (score 0):

For this view composers can be used. So inside a global service provider you need to add this.

```
view()->share('currentUser', User);
```

*Where **User** is the authenticated user.*

> Documentation about view composers can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers) for this.